# Repeat query for every value in a column and union all results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a query which gives me top 3 salaries for the **specific department id**. For example for `DepartmentId=100`:

```
select distinct top 3 e.Id, e.Salary, dep.Id
from Employee e
inner join Department dep on e.DepartmentId = dep.Id and dep.Id = 100
```

and it's working fine.

Now, I want to run previous query for **every department id** and union all results. Something like this (written in a pseudocode):

```
Result <- empty
foreach depId in [Department].id
    Result = Result UNION run previous query with depId (insead of 100)
```

How can I achive this with SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `APPLY`

```
select t.Id, t.Salary, t.DepartmentId
from Department dep 
cross apply (
    select distinct top 3 e.Id, e.Salary, e.DepartmentId
    from Employee e
    where e.DepartmentId = dep.Id) t
```

This will only return `Employee` rows for which parent `Department` exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the department's `id` in the results (and not its name also) then the join is not necessary because this id exists in the table `Employee`.
Use [`row_number()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) window function:

```
select e.Id, e.Salary, e.DepartmentId
from (
  select 
    Id, Salary, DepartmentId,
    row_number() over (partition by DepartmentId order by Salary desc) rn
  from Employee
) e
where e.rn <= 3
```